# Check whether disk exists in applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm making an apple script to unmount a volume when I don't need it and then mount it again once I click on the application...

Im creating it in automator and the code looks like this:

```
if disk "UNIVERSAL" exists then

    do shell script "diskutil unmount /volumes/UNIVERSAL"

  else

    do shell script "diskutil mount /volumes/UNIVERSAL"

end if
```

I get an error at the `disk "UNIVERSAL" exists` please help...

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using the Finder is this...

```
set diskName to "UNIVERSAL"

if diskName is in (do shell script "/bin/ls /Volumes") then
    -- unmount
else
    -- mount
end if
```

Answer (score 4):

Is the if statement within a tell application "Finder" block?

```
tell application "Finder"
if disk "Mac OS X" exists then
    beep
end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

- Checking if folder exists is not really safe, what if a previous mount failed?
- What if there is a directory mounted UNIVERSAL-1 or UNIVERSAL MOVIES... etc

A more secure and more close alternative to the Finder would be

```
set theVolume to "/Volumes/UNIVERSAL"
set mountedVolumes to every paragraph of (do shell script "mount | awk -F' on ' '{print $2}' | awk -F' \\\\(' '{print $1}'")
if theVolume is in mountedVolumes then
    --Volume is mounted
else
    --volume is not mounted
end if
```